# How to create a column with means obtained from groupby function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe CGdf_2004 as below:

```
Region,   Sector,   TSR_15_16
Europe    Consumer  12%
Americas  Telecom   15%
...so on 7000 rows
```

I have calculated the mean TSR_15_16 grouping by sector and region.

`X = CGdf_2004.groupby(['Region', 'Sector']).mean()`

Now I want to create a new column in CGdf_2004 that has these means based on the sector and region. So, I want the mean for (Europe and Consumer) written to a new column for every row that has Europe and Consumer together.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use join.

```
X=CGdf_2004.groupby(['Region', 'Sector']).mean()
CGdf_2004.join(X, on=['Region', 'Sector'], rsuffix='_mean')
```

In one line

```
CGdf_2004.join(CGdf_2004.groupby(['Region', 'Sector']).mean(), on=['Region', 'Sector'], rsuffix='_mean')
```

Comment: @user3021495 don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem